# Matplotlib, button to close a loop, python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot that allows user to click on a data point. Then it generates a continuous loop that was supposed to be closed by clicking on the close button. The example below will trigger a print message of "Still Looping" every 1second. Then I created a button hoping to close the loop by changing loopBool to True. But it doesn't work because once the loop starts I am not able to interact with the figure window. How can I solve this? Many thanks

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time
import matplotlib.widgets as widgets
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# it is not always column 0 and 1
sctPlot = ax.scatter([-0.3,0,0.3], [0.3,0.3,0.3],  c="blue", picker = 2, s=[50]*3)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3, left=0.1)
plt.grid(False)
plt.axis([-0.6, 0.6, -0.6, 0.6])

loopBool = True

def closeLooping(event):
    global loopBool
    loopBool = False

def looping(event):
    global loopBool
    while (loopBool == True):
        print "Still Looping!"
        time.sleep(1)
    print "Stop!!"

axCloseButton = plt.axes([0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.06])
bClose = Button(axCloseButton, "Close", color = axcolor, hovercolor = '0.975')
bClose.on_clicked(closeLooping)


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', looping)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that a process stuck in an infinite loop is in a sense incompatible with a GUI. GUIs themselves perform a loop, checking for and responding to events happening. The best solution would probably be to remove your infinite loop, by transforming that part of code to an event-based one.

However, I also found a solution to your actual problem. I'm not very familiar with the programming constructs involved, so I can't tell you how efficient or elegant this solution is. The point is to run your infinite loop in a separate thread, thereby preventing your main python process from being stuck in the loop. This will keep the GUI responsive. However, this can lead to problems if you want to interrupt your program during its run.

The code:

```
import time
import threading #this is new
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets as widgets

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# it is not always column 0 and 1
sctPlot = ax.scatter([-0.3,0,0.3], [0.3,0.3,0.3],  c="blue", picker = 2, s=[50]*3)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3, left=0.1)
plt.grid(False)
plt.axis([-0.6, 0.6, -0.6, 0.6])

loopBool = True

def closeLooping(event):
    global loopBool
    loopBool = False

def looping(event):
    global loopBool
    while (loopBool == True):
        print("Still Looping!")
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Stop!!")

def looping_pre(event): #this is new
    thread = threading.Thread(target=looping, args=(event,))
    #thread.daemon = True   #might or might not be needed
    thread.start()

axCloseButton = plt.axes([0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.06])
bClose = widgets.Button(axCloseButton, "Close", hovercolor = '0.975')
bClose.on_clicked(closeLooping)
plt.show() #this is new

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', looping_pre) #this is changed
```

Note that I changed a few things because your exact code didn't seem to run properly for me. I removed `color=axcolor` from the `Button` call; and I added a `plt.show()` before the event connect, otherwise a figure window didn't appear for me (neither through `ipython`, nor with `python`).

The relevant addition is the `threading` module and the `looping_pre` front-end, which calls the `looping` function as a separate `Thread`. For this reason the `'pick_event'` doesn't call `looping`, but rather `looping_pre`.

This code will (when running in `ipython`) show the figure window, start looping on a click to the data, then stop looping on button click. However, when I push ctrl+c, the loop keeps on going, since it is a separate thread. I only managed to kill it by using a `reset`, thereby removing the value of the `global loopBool`. The commented line specifying whether the `Thread` should be `deamon`ized *should* affect this behaviour (by which I mean that it would seem logical to me), but I didn't see any effect.